# PHP mail not functioning

Tags: php, contact-form

My PHP contact form does not send my email anywhere, be it Inbox or Spam.
The PHP is the latest edition and is running on a server which has SMTP installed on it.
I'm unsure whether it's my code or software...

Heres my php contact script:

```
    <?php
$to = "FILTERED";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'] ." From: " .$_POST['email'];
$from =    "contactform@contact.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

and my form:

```
<form method='post' action='contactscript.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>
```

Comment: You need to var_dump(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) and see if that comes back true or false.

Comment: and you are sure that everything is okay until it reaches the `mail()`?

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the problem lies in your code or in the external software, check the return value of `mail()`.

```
if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
    echo "Message was sent";
}
else {
    echo "Sending failed.";
}
```

If it returns false, the error lies in your script, or the message was not accepted for delivery by your mail server.

Comment: I got a "Sending failed." message, though I see no problem in my code?

Comment: If you have confirmed there are no problems with your code (by closely examining the values for $to, $subject, $message, and $headers), your message is not being accepted by your mail server. You will need to examine the server logs to find out why.

Comment: The server logs do not show my emails getting accepted or denied, they're blank

Comment: Do you have the correct setting in your php.ini file for `SMTP` (Windows) or `sendmail_from` and `sendmail_path`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope - $to = "FILTERED"; means you are putting the filtered email addresses in $to. If mail() is failing, you should get an error in PHP. Enable error reporting or check the log file. If mail() is not failing then it's no more a PHP issue, you should check the mail server. You can also try to send a mail using mail() with hard-coded values to see if the mail goes out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a space after the From colon?

```
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

->

```
$headers = "From: " . $from;
```

But yes, either var_dump, or echo out mail():

```
echo mail($blah,...);
```

1 is success, 0 would be failure.

Also, $to doesn't seem to be a valid email address..

Answer (score 0):

I would outsource it using something like [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) with a free plan of 200 messages per day. It makes sure your messages don't get flagged as spam because it using DKIM/SPF(not that easy to handle yourself) plus you don't have to worry about scaling.

---

Answer (score 0):

Although you can change this with params and config variables, php mail() uses sendmail by default. If it is not installed in the standard location and you do not configure it explicitly to use another method, mail() will fail.